# Different behavior development production

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm experience a weird problem. I'm developing an iOS (iPhone) application and I'm testing it with hockey app. I experience a different behavior between development and production.
In some circustamahce (some of them are reproducible other not) the application crash when it's running in production and I don't experience the same problem when I install the same application using Xcode on my testing device.

All of this crash are:

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0xb
Crashed Thread:  0
```

I'm assume this are memory management error (even if I'm using ARC I could have done something wrong) but the question is: why is the application is behaving differently in the two environment? how can I reproduce these problem on my local device?

Comment: You don't have a crash log or anything?  This information tells us nothing....I know that one reason my app misbehaved with release mode was I was doing too much stuff inside `NSAssert`, which becomes nothing when compiled in release mode.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/a1350d0e59d0c3b18190, this is the complete crash log. I'm using RestKIT which is using NSAssert extensively but can't assume that's the problem. are you aware of any other difference between the two enviroment? do you have any other suggestion given the information of the crash log?

Comment: Hard to say for sure, but something is going wrong in your delegate when you receive data back from the server.  It looks like sending a message to an object that isn't the correct type.  This can happen more in release mode since the compiler heavily optimizes memory locations, etc.  In debug mode you might have the same object in the same location every time but that's never true in release mode.  Something might be going out of scope...

Comment: it makes sense. do you have suggestions for debugging this kind of problem?

Comment: You could try going into your build settings and turning on optimization for debug mode and see if some problems come out...